# Dataframe Groupby ID to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to convert the following dataframe into a JSON file:

```
id     email    surveyname question  answer 
 1   lol@gmail       s          1      apple
 1   lol@gmail       s          3      apple/juice
 1   lol@gmail       s          2      apple-pie
 1   lol@gmail       s          4      apple-pie
 1   lol@gmail       s          5      apple|pie|yes
 1   lol@gmail       s          6      apple
 1   lol@gmail       s          8      apple
 1   lol@gmail       s          7      apple
 1   lol@gmail       s          9      apple
 1   lol@gmail       s          12     apple
 1   lol@gmail       s          11     apple
 1   lol@gmail       s          10     apple_sauce
 2   ll@gmail        s          1      orange
 2   ll@gmail        s          3      juice
 .
 .
```

To:

```
{
  "df":[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "email:"lol@gmail"
      "surveyname":"s",
      "1":"apple",
      "2":"apple-pie",
      "3":"apple/juice",
      "4":"apple-pie",
      "5":"apple|pie|yes",
      "6":"apple",
      "7":"apple",
      "8":"apple",
      "9":"apple",
      "10":"apple_sauce",
      "11":"apple",
      "12":"apple"
    },
    {
      "id": "vid",
      "email:"llgmail"
      "surveyname: "s"
      "1":"orange",
      "2":"",                        # empty
      "3":"juice",
      .
      .
      .
    }
  ]
}
```

It should map all the ids in the df and skip the numbers if they're empty.

Below is a sample for the df I used above. If the whole df for id = 2 needs to be constructed, please let me know and I can edit that in. However, some entries don't have completed values inside the actual df.

```
d = {'id': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1,
  11: 1,
  12: 2,
  13: 2},
 'email': {0: 'lol@gmail',
  1: 'lol@gmail',
  2: 'lol@gmail',
  3: 'lol@gmail',
  4: 'lol@gmail',
  5: 'lol@gmail',
  6: 'lol@gmail',
  7: 'lol@gmail',
  8: 'lol@gmail',
  9: 'lol@gmail',
  10: 'lol@gmail',
  11: 'lol@gmail',
  12: 'll@gmail',
  13: 'll@gmail'},
 'surveyname': {0: 's',
  1: 's',
  2: 's',
  3: 's',
  4: 's',
  5: 's',
  6: 's',
  7: 's',
  8: 's',
  9: 's',
  10: 's',
  11: 's',
  12: 's',
  13: 's'},
 'question': {0: 1,
  1: 3,
  2: 2,
  3: 4,
  4: 5,
  5: 6,
  6: 8,
  7: 7,
  8: 9,
  9: 12,
  10: 11,
  11: 10,
  12: 1,
  13: 3},
 'answer': {0: 'apple',
  1: 'apple/juice',
  2: 'apple-pie',
  3: 'apple-pie',
  4: 'apple|pie|yes',
  5: 'apple',
  6: 'apple',
  7: 'apple',
  8: 'apple',
  9: 'apple',
  10: 'apple',
  11: 'apple_sauce',
  12: 'orange',
  13: 'juice'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Comment: does each id have 12 questions?

Comment: some may have less, like 11. but never more than 12. does that limit the json object? i am unfamiliar with json objects

Comment: If number of questions are not equal across ids, how do we know if we should fill in an empty string (as you did at `"2":"",                        # empty`) or not?

Comment: well , its supposed to be 12 but some are missing like id = 2, so the number should be equal across ids but some are missing values and i was hoping to write an empty string in those. in the example i just truncated the df for space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot the dataframe before exporting to JSON:

```py
(
    df.pivot_table(
        index=["id", "email", "surveyname"],
        columns="question",
        values="answer",
        aggfunc="first",
    )
    .reindex(columns=np.arange(1, 13))
    .fillna("")
    .reset_index()
    .to_json("data.json", orient="records")
)
```